# Is there a way to detect the main ROI?

Tags: image-processing, opencv, computer-vision, javacv

i want detect the important ROI Element in a picture. (i want to get the position)
I've tested a reverted [SeamCarving-Method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seam_carving). I hoped, that the most importand Area in a picture have the most energylevel. I've generated one vertical and one horizontal Seam and took the intersection. But this method don't seem to be perfect.
Some examples:

good detection:
[good detection http://img713.imageshack.us/img713/2928/seamcastle.jpg](http://img713.imageshack.us/img713/2928/seamcastle.jpg)
[good detection http://img39.imageshack.us/img39/9584/seamente.jpg](http://img39.imageshack.us/img39/9584/seamente.jpg)
[good detection http://img193.imageshack.us/img193/2693/seamwuffi.jpg](http://img193.imageshack.us/img193/2693/seamwuffi.jpg)

near aceptable;
[good detection http://img440.imageshack.us/img440/7459/seamflower.jpg](http://img440.imageshack.us/img440/7459/seamflower.jpg)

worse detection:

[good detection http://img836.imageshack.us/img836/5766/seamsun.jpg](http://img836.imageshack.us/img836/5766/seamsun.jpg) (maybe the point is a good result. It's the point with the max. energylevel in this picture)

[good detection http://img507.imageshack.us/img507/2750/seambluesky1.jpg](http://img507.imageshack.us/img507/2750/seambluesky1.jpg)

Have anyone a idea to detect roi's more better?

greeting,
desire

Comment: it says GIMP has implemented it and it is opensource. what about checking their code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the key terms you are looking for is: Saliency Detection, Salient Object Detection, etc

Perhaps these papers will point you in the right direction:

- A Model of Saliency-Based Visual Attention for Rapid Scene Analysis ([PDF](http://www.lira.dist.unige.it/teaching/SINA_08-09/papers/itti98model.pdf))
- Simulating Human Saccadic Scanpaths on Natural Images ([PDF](http://www.psy.pku.edu.cn/Upload/pubs/2011062100003.pdf))
- Salient Object Detection by Composition ([PDF](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/people/yichenw/iccv11_salientobjectdetection.pdf))
- Saliency Filters: Contrast Based Filtering for Salient Region Detection ([Web](http://www.fedeperazzi.com/saliency_filters/))

Comment: is there any good solutions for opencv/javacv? I've found some implementations which uses pointer arithmetics. But they are very difficult to convert to java

Comment: Sorry, I am unfamiliar with any implementations. We have a student in my institute (different supervisor) who is working on this in Matlab. The other supervisor is currently unavailable. Pointer arithmetic is usually done for efficiency, is it possible that you replace that part with a naive implementation. Or can you use the existing implementations to look at the results, to see if this is really the correct approach?

Comment: Jeah, in C++ Pointer arithmic is more efficiency, of course. I'm working with Java(CV). There is a class, which emulates the pointer structur. But i think it need more space and time. I've found the paper "Frequency-tuned Salient Region Detection".The implementation sounds easy, so i will try it later.